# Apply an FilterInputStream to a Channel

Tags: java, nio

How can I apply a FilterInputStream to an NIO Channel, specifically a FileChannel obtained from a RandomAccessFile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.nio.channels.*;
InputStream in = new MyFilterInputStream(Channels.newInputStream(channel));
```

But then why the channel?

Comment: The channel obtained from RandomAccessFile is allows concurrent reads and writes, without needing to move the file pointer. Unfortunately I'll lose this if I use an InputStream. It doesn't look like there's a drop-in way to manipulate bytes as read from a Channel. If you have suggestions for how to do this without using an InputStream, I'd love to hear them!

Comment: @skyler how to do what? You said you wanted to use an input stream; this is how. There is no such thing as using a FilterInputStream without an InputStream, as its constructors show.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the below working example:

[Using FileChannel to random access to a File](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/UsingFileChanneltorandomaccesstoaFile.htm)

Comment: Both this link, and the URL referenced within it, do not work.

Comment: Sorry Skyler. Now that I tested the posted link. you can try it out. :)

Comment: Thanks Kris, but this doesn't address using a FilterInputStream. If using a FilterInputStream with a Channel isn't possible, what is the preferred way of manipulating bytes as they're read from or written to a channel?